# Visual Studio Open & Close another form with button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want runbtn can open 10 thread of Form2, than stopbtn can close all the Form2, after stopbtn close all the Form2 I want runbtn can reopen all the Form2 again.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form2 formAction = new Form2();
        private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formAction.Show();  
        }

        private void stopbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            formAction.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep track of them in a list?

Comment: Forms don't run on different threads.  Pretty unclear from your code example what you are trying to do.  If you have 10 Form2s open, which form does the Stop button close?  The last one?  The first one?  Need more context.

Comment: all of the 10 form2s will be close if click the stop button

Comment: Then put those forms in a `List<Form>`.  Update your post if you can't get the code to work.

Comment: so I must make 10 forms? thats not what I want it.

Comment: That's what you told us.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I open 10 thread of Form2 with runbtn, close all the Form2 with stopbtn, than I can re-open all the Form2 again with runbtn. Thanks for all help.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
        List<Form> formAction;
        private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (formAction == null)
            {
                formAction = new List<Form>() {
                new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2(),
                new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2(), new Form2()
                };
                foreach (var form in formAction)
                {
                    form.Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Form already open!");
            }                     
        }
        private void stopbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (formAction == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It's already close!");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var form in formAction)
                {
                    form.Close();
                    formAction = null;
                }
            }            
        }        
    }
}
```